# JavaScript custom validation not working

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitform() {
        if(document.getElementById('name').value=='') {
            alert('Please enter a name');
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
<form action="mail.php" method="post" onsubmit="submitform();">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

as expected, the form when submitted should call the submitform function, and if the name field is blank, it should return false and give an alert.
But, it just goes through.
Any explainations?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function with return, so that the *false* value prevents default action (form submission)

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post" onsubmit="return submitform();">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: that's the proper way, be sure to refresh properly and clear cache

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop a little.

You can use onSubmit, but it's best to delete your input submit and put a button.
Then on button click you can do what you want and eventually submit the form

Form:

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post" id="mailForm">
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name">
<button id="submitMailForm">Submit</button>
```

JS:

```
$( document ).on( "click", "#submitMailForm", function(e) {
 //My control Here
 //If all ok
 $("#mailForm").submit();
});
```

Comment: Putting the listener on the button is a poor solution. It is far more commonly recommended (for good reasons) to put submit validation listeners on the form.

Comment: @RobG Why it's a poor solution and where is it recommended? For which reason?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery instead of javascript for this kind of validation is will be very easy to implement.

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
</form>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#submit").click(fucntion(e){
        if($("#name").val() == ""){
       alert("Name is empty");
       e.preventDefault();
     }
     });
   });
</script>
```

And dont forget to add jquery library before the script tag.

Comment: That's one solution. But I need to know why doesn't the javascript thingy work!

Comment: The function you have written returns a value but you are not letting the form know what is the return so by default it understand true. so you need to change you form onsubmit to onsubmit="return submitform();" in this way your form will get the value from function and if false it will not submit.

Comment: jQuery is javascript. You've successfully replaced plain JS with even more jQuery (not counting the several thousand lines of jQuery itself). Cool.

Comment: @RobG Yes, I have replaced Plain JS with jquery because its easy to use and not very much complicated to use. I understand your words about the jquery library thousands of line of codes. But as per my understanding that jquery library is so much optimized that it will not take took much time to load and which will hamper the page loading time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `onSubmit` attribute as follows

```
onsubmit="return submitform();"
```

So your html look like this

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post" onsubmit="return submitform();">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: None of them look my answer. I was posted the solution first :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitform(event) {
        if(document.getElementById('name').value=='') {
            alert('Please enter a name');
             event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>

<form action="mail.php" method="post" onsubmit="submitform(event);">
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

You need to prevent default of submit. In JS return false does not stop the propagation of the "submit" function (with frameworks can be different).

I suggest you to read:
[event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Answer (score 0):

just try this script

```
function submitform() {
    var x = document.forms["fname"].value;
    x = x.trim(); // Remove white spaces
    if (x==null || x=="") {
        alert("First name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To cancel submission, the listener needs to return true or false. Also, if the function validates the fields, far better to name it for what it does rather than when it does it so call it something like "validateForm".

Also, giving a control a name of "name" masks the form's own *name* property. While that doesn't matter here, in general it's not a good idea to give any form control a name that is the same as a standard property of a form (e.g. "submit" or "reset").

So you might end up with something like:

```
<script>
    function validateForm(form) {
        if (form.personName.value == '') {
            alert('Please enter a name');
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>

<form ... onsubmit="return validateForm(this);">
    <input type="text" name="personName">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```